# django redirection issues. Objects not loaded correctly

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a blog. Home page of the blog will contain summary about the blog posts (ordered by date).

When the user clicks on the title of the blog post on the home page, page for that post should open up.

So I am trying to the above and running into some problems.

Here is what the `post.html` file looks like (file that would display full post) :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{%block content %}

<div class="mainContent">
    <div class = "Content">
        <article class = "Typical Article">
            <header>
                <h3><a href="/blog/{{post.id}}">{{post.title}}.....{{post.id}}</a></h3>
            </header>

            <footer>
                <p class = "postInfo">Sukhvir Notra, {{post.date}}</p>
            </footer>

            <content>
                <p>{{post.summary|safe|linebreaks}}</p>
            </content>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>

{%endblock%}
```

And here is the urls.py file inside my app:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns,include ,url
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from blog.models import blog

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',ListView.as_view(queryset=blog.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:20],template_name="blog.html")),

    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$',DetailView.as_view(model = blog,template_name="post.html")),

    url(r'^archives$',ListView.as_view(queryset=blog.objects.all().order_by("-date"),template_name="archives.html")),

    url(r'^latestnews$',ListView.as_view(queryset=blog.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:10],template_name="archives.html")),

    )
```

the problem is when I click on the title on the home page, New page opens up with correct url (127.0.0.1/blog/1 --- 1 being the post.id)

but the page is blank and all I see on the page is  `.....`. which tells me that `{{post.id}},{{post.title}}` variables are not working properly.

What may be causing this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the context_object_name in your urls to the name you want your object to have in your template.

eg:

```
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$',DetailView.as_view(model = blog,template_name="post.html", context_object_name="post")),
```

Django uses a default context object with the name `object` (for DetailView) or `object_list` (for ListView) unless otherwise specified.